# Inverse laplace transform using equating coeffecients method

Tags: laplace-transform

Please see attached image. Could you please help me do the inverse of this laplace transfrom. I'm using the method of trying to equate the coeffecients.

Thanks
[image: Question]

Comment: You mean Partial Fractions? $\dfrac{3}{s+1}+\dfrac{12}{3 s+1}-\dfrac{6}{s}$

Comment: Yes, how did end up getting the coeffecients? I'm always get complex/irration numbers for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\color{blue}{3(s^2-3s-2)}}{s(s+1)(3s+1)}=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s+1}+\frac{C}{3 s+1}=\frac{\color{blue}{A(s+1)(3s+1)+Bs(3s+1)+Cs(s+1)}}{s(s+1)(3s+1)}$$

Thus we must have
$$
3s^2-9s-6=(3A+3B+C) s^2+(4 A+B+C) s+A
$$
and equating the same power we have $3A+3B+C=3$, $4 A+B+C=-9$ and $A=-6$, and then $B=3$ and $C=12$
that is
$$
\overline{x}(s)=\frac{3(s^2-3s-2)}{s(s+1)(3s+1)}=-\frac{6}{s}+\frac{3}{s+1}+\frac{12}{3 s+1}=-\frac{6}{s}+\frac{3}{s+1}+\frac{4}{s+\frac{1}{3}}
$$
and 
$$
x(t)=-6u(t)+3 u(t)\mathrm e^{-t}+4 u(t) \mathrm e^{-t/3}
$$